# Viewing the value of the variable in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am compeletely new to **Oracle-PLSQL**. I have to convert a `TSQL` function to `PLSQL`. So I need to declare variable, set values inside of it and use them. This is a very very simple code:

```
declare LoopCounter INT ;
begin
      Select MIN(RankNumber) into LoopCounter 
      From 
      (
            Select  Substation , ColumnTitle,S6_name,AVNR
            ,Rank() Over(Order By Substation , ColumnTitle,S6_name)  RankNumber
            From PREREPORT
      )  RankGroup;

 end;
```

This Code now is being tested in Sql Developer. How can I check the Variable LoopCounter ?
I have set the SET SERVEROUTPUT ON and used the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LoopCounter); for displaying the value of the value but nothing has been shown.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_output.htm#TTPLP71215

Comment: @KaushikNayak: I had added the line DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LoopCounter); with dbms_output enabled and buffer size 20000 . but it shows nothing

Comment: which tool are you using ? Have you tried adding `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`?

Comment: @KaushikNayak: Yes I have set it. and I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Have you checked running the query, does it return any rows?

Comment: @KaushikNayak: totally sure and it returns a value of Min function

Comment: Your image displays the `Script Output` tab, which is for showing SQL\*Plus output. Underneath it is another labelled `DBMS Output`: have you looked at that one? What does it say?

Comment: @KaushikNayak: I have this message in script debugger "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." and DBMS Out is empty

Comment: Is your DBMS_OUTPUT window connnected to your schema?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Developer choose `View/dbms output` option. The `dbms-output` pane should appear somwhere in the window.
Next click a big green `plus` icon in this pane, and select your active session there. This session shoul appear in this pane, see the printscreen below
[image]

---

Next execute the procedure - just hit Ctrl-Enter to run it. This is my test procedure:

```
DECLARE
  x int;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO x 
  FROM dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( x );
END;
/
```

---

when the procedure is done, you should see the result of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE command in the DBMS-output pane:

[[image: enter image description here[2]]

Comment: @krokodiko: I have done the exact steps you have mentioned but it shows nothing in DBMS Output

Comment: Try restarting SQLDev... something is weird with your SQLDev, that should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used same code but with Different table it Works perfectly. I would Suggest to check SQL Statement Separately if you are able to get some result.(Checked the Code in LiveSQL.oracle.com)

```
declare  
LoopCounter INT ; 
begin 
      Select MIN(RankNumber) into LoopCounter  
      From  
      ( 
            Select  ename , Job,mgr 
            ,Rank() Over(Order By ename , job,mgr)  RankNumber 
            From scott.emp 
      )  RankGroup; 

      dbms_output.put_line(Loopcounter); 

 end;
```

Comment: I have done that it shows nothing. I have mentioned what I have done above.

Comment: We run dbms_output.get_line() after your block of code ends to display the output from the buffer @nnmmss - make sure your session has proper privs on dbms_output - it's granted to PUBLIC, so shouldn't be an issue, but you never know what someone has done to their db install/config

Comment: 'Select  Substation , ColumnTitle,S6_name,AVNR
            ,Rank() Over(Order By Substation , ColumnTitle,S6_name)  RankNumber
            From PREREPORT'

Check if  above code is returning any data