# Oracle PL/SQL: modify a variable using a loop and return the result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Suppose I have this dummy table.

```
create table dummy_table as
select 'A' letter from dual
union all
select 'B' letter from dual;
```

... and need to concatenate all values from the letter column into one clob variable, each value beginning on a new line.

I've been trying something along these lines, but it doesn't work as my knowledge of PL/SQL is unfortunately limited. The code below isn't working, but conveys the idea.

```
var my_text clob; -- def? define? declare?

begin
 for c in ( select letter from dummy_table ) 
  loop
    my_text := my_text  || c.letter || chr(10);
  end loop;
end;
```

In the end, need to be able to output the result

```
print(my_text); -- dbms_output.put_line(my_text)? dbms_sql.return_result(my_text)?
```

While it says `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`, printing `my_value` returns an empty variable.

Using SQL Developer and Oracle 19c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VAR` is short for `VARIABLE` and is an SQL*Plus command that defines a bind variable for use in the client application (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or SQLcl). It is not a PL/SQL command. Similarly, `PRINT` is an SQL*Plus command and is not part of the SQL or PL/SQL languages.

If you want to use a bind variable then you need to prefix it with `:` when you are using it in SQL or PL/SQL.

```sql
VARIABLE my_text clob;

BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT letter FROM dummy_table) 
  LOOP
    :my_text := :my_text  || c.letter || chr(10);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

PRINT my_text;

-- or

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:my_text);
END;
/
```

However, if you want to do it in a PL/SQL block (and not using client-base bind variables) then `DECLARE` a local variable and use that:

```sql
DECLARE
  my_text CLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

  FOR c IN (SELECT letter FROM dummy_table) 
  LOOP
    my_text := my_text  || c.letter || chr(10);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_text);
END;
/
```

Comment: Using a `:` prefix worked! But other options using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` didn't. In the 1st case where var is created outside PL/SQL block, calling `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:my_text)` pops up an "Enter Binds" window prompt, which is empty. The 2nd option inside PL/SQL block is `successfully completed`, but shows no other output.

Comment: Figured it out, needs to be viewed in [Dbms output panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50422578/2753688).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a function that returns a clob and display the result using `dbms_output`:

```
koen 19c > create table dummy_table as
  2  select 'A' letter from dual
  3  union all
  4* select 'B' letter from dual;

Table DUMMY_TABLE created.

koen 19c > create or replace function print_concatenated_text return clob as 
  2    l_my_text clob; 
  3  begin
  4   for c in ( select letter from dummy_table ) 
  5    loop
  6      l_my_text := l_my_text  || c.letter || chr(10);
  7    end loop;
  8    return l_my_text;
  9  end print_concatenated_text;
 10* /

Function PRINT_CONCATENATED_TEXT compiled

koen 19c > set serveroutput on
koen 19c > begin 
  2     dbms_output.put_line(print_concatenated_text);
  3  end;
  4* /
A
B



PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```