# Oracle PL/SQL: workarounds around DBMS output size limitation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

This question follows from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77482210/2753688), but I ran into another different issue.

I am generating a large text output using PL/SQL

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000; -- maximum limit
declare my_text clob;    
begin
 for c in ( select letter from dummy_table ) 
  loop
    my_text := my_text  || c.letter || chr(10);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(my_text);
end;
```

In the real code, I am of course not just concatenating single letters, the strings are longer and the concatenation has more elements and is longer overall. I have already increased the output buffer size to 1000000 (which is maximum), which helped, but as I expanded the concatenation further, is started failing again - but now with a different error message that has nothing to do with size of the output, but I know experimentally that it does, since if I reduce the number of lines it works.

[image]

Is it possible to save the clob into a temporary table? Is clob the right data type to use here?

Comment: This feels like an XY-problem. You are having errors that the DBSM_OUTPUT buffer is too small but why do you need to use DBMS_OUTPUT at all? You have a CLOB that contains all the data, why not save it to a file or insert it into a table and then you can read it from that location? Stop using DBMS_OUTPUT and use something else.

Comment: @MT0 could you give pointers on how to insert this clob into a table?

Comment: Documentation on [DBMS_OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-3C2FDFF2-4A8A-4555-988C-7AA3D0FF7971) provides this advice: *The package is typically used for debugging, or for displaying messages and reports to SQL\*DBA or SQL\*Plus (such as are produced by applying the SQL command DESCRIBE to procedures).* If you want to build a clob ant return it to the client, then do this in the function and process the result on a caller

Comment: 1000000 is not the maximum. You can `set servoutput on size unlimited` https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-5EA17047-1EBC-44BA-A21A-B4CEC27FD6B0 However @MTO is right, dbms_output is the wrong tool here (and taking unlimited PGA memory on the database server is somewhat risky).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feels like an XY-problem and the solution is to not use `DBMS_OUTPUT` rather than trying to work around something you probably cannot change.

Create a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (datetime DATE, value CLOB);
```

Then just `INSERT` into the table:

```sql
DECLARE
  my_text clob;    
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT letter FROM dummy_table)
  LOOP
    my_text := my_text  || c.letter || chr(10);
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO table_name (datetime, value) VALUES (SYSDATE, my_text);
END;
/
```

You could, equivalently, write the `CLOB` to a file.

Then use whatever client application (SQL Developer, Java, PHP, etc.) you are using to read the `CLOB` value from the table.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DgNMZqQ2)